# BLE Connection dropping

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, data-stream

I am trying to stream data using BLE but the device does not stay connected. Currently, we can connect and print out all the UUIDs of services and characteristics and establish connection. It connects to the BLE device for very short period of time then the device is not connected to the application afterwards.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ConnectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    BluetoothDevice connectDevice;
    BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt;
    List<BluetoothGattService> services;
    private Queue<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> chars;

    private static final String DAQSERVICE = "FFD7";

    private static final String SAMPLING_RATE_UUID = "FFD8";
    private static final String DATA_UUID = "FFD9";
    private static final String BATTERY_UUID = "FFDA";
    private static final String CONTROL_UUID = "FFDB";
    private static final String TAG = "error";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_button);
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        chars = new LinkedList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    streamData();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    //pop up bluetooth settings menu if we cannot find device
    void streamData() throws IOException {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            if (device.getName().equals("Connection Test")) {

                connectDevice = device;
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                System.out.println("connecting to gatt");
                bluetoothGatt = connectDevice.connectGatt(this, false, btleGattCallback);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("New API")
    private BluetoothGattCallback btleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            //this will get called anytime you perform a read or write characteristic operation
            byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            System.out.print("data buffer updated: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(data[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status, final int newState) {
            // this will get called when a device connects or disconnects
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                discoverServices();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status) {
            // this will get called after the client initiates a BluetoothGatt.discoverServices() call
            //getServices();
            Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getServices();
                }
            });
            workerThread.start();
            try{
                workerThread.join();
                System.out.println("joined thread");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onDescriptorRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            byte[] data = descriptor.getValue();
            System.out.print("data buffer updated: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(data[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            System.out.println("in read");
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                System.out.println("UUID: " + characteristic.getUuid());
                byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
                System.out.println("reading");
                for (byte temp : data) {
                    System.out.print(temp);
                }
            }
        }

        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status){
            System.out.println("in write");
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                System.out.println("UUID: " + characteristic.getUuid());
                byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
                System.out.println("reading in write mode");
                System.out.println(new String(data));
            }
        }
    };

    void discoverServices() {
        System.out.println("discovering services");
        bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
    }

    void getServices() {
        System.out.println("getting services");
        services = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
        System.out.println("number of services: " + services.size());
        for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
            System.out.println("service uuid: " + service.getUuid().toString());
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics){
                    System.out.println("characteristic uuid: " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());

                    bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
                    for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor : characteristic.getDescriptors()) {
                        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
                    }
                    bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("got all services");
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find out the solution for the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need find out where the problem is.

The remote device? does other mobile phone and apps can connect with your remote device? you also may check the RF, and the clock of the remote device.